# React 18 typeof useCallback not exported

Tags: reactjs

I'm upgrading to React 18 and am having trouble with the `typeof useCallback`. I used to be able to do this:

```
import type { UseCallback } from 'react'

interface MyComponentProps {
  onChange: UseCallback<(value: boolean) => void>;
}
```

However, now `UseCallback` is no longer exported from react and I'm getting an error when doing this:

```
type CallbackFn = (value: boolean) => void;

interface MyComponentProps {
  onChange: ReturnType<typeof useCallback<CallbackFn>>.  //Parsing error: '>' expected.eslint
}
```

Does anyone know how to enforces users pass onChange wrapped by `useCallback`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to enforce that a function has been passed through useCallback as it doesn't change the type of the function. The useCallback typescript definition is:

```
    function useCallback<T extends Function>(callback: T, deps: DependencyList): T;
```

It takes in a function with type T, and returns type T, so they are indistinguishable.

The only way I can think of to handle this is to make your own wrapper around useCallback which returns something of the format `{fn: T, __isCallback: true}`, and having your prop accept that type. Technically developers could manually pass that object in too, but it would guide them towards using the return of your custom `useCallbackTyped`.